# Thread.join() and Thread.interrupt() doesn't stop the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I'm having some issues with stopping my threads.
I've tried calling both `Thread.join()` and `Thread.interrupt()`, alone and together, but I can't get it working.
I have a `while` loop in each class, which runs as long as a boolean called `running` equals to `true`.
I then stop the program by calling a method called `stop`. The `stop` method only sets `running` to false, so that the while loop exits.

**EDIT** Code:

```
public class Game implements Runnable {

    // The Thread
    private Thread thread;

    // The program's running state
    private boolean running = false;

    // Create the Thread and the rest of the application
    public void create() {
        // Create the Thread
        thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
        // Start the Thread
        thread.start();
        // Set the program's running state to true
        running = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            // Render, update etc...
        }

        // When the while loop has exited
        // (when running is false (when the stop method has been called))
        try {
            // Join the thread
            thread.join();
            // Interrupt the thread
            thread.interrupt();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            // Print the exception message
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Exit the program
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Stop the game
    public void stop() {
        // Set the program's running state to false
        running = false;
    }

    // The main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of Game and start it
        new Game().create();
    }
```

Comment: Not enough code. Note that the standard way to check whether a thread is interrupted is to check for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. Read the javadoc carefully. Or better yet, do not use threads directly and use an `ExecutorService`. And buy JCIP.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention I'm creaing a game, so to not use threads is not an option. Also, how much code do you need?

Comment: Do you really think that join() and interrupt() will set your `running` variable to false? Is that what the javadoc of those methods say it does?

Comment: That is the base of it. I put all rendering etc. inside of the loop.

Comment: You are misunderstanding; read the docs of `ExecutorService`: it does manage threads for you.

Comment: Put the code of your thread class; put the code where you create it and try to stop it; also tell what GUI toolkit you are using.

Comment: What is a GUI toolkit?

Comment: I'm writing from my phone

Comment: Okay. Now I've updated the code.

Comment: I think you should explain what you *expect* that code to do. Do you understand the semantics of `Thread.join()` and `Thread.interrupt()`? Looking at your code, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Presumably something else is calling stop(). One option would be to mark "running" as volatile, but a better solution would be to use a  java.util.concurrent.AtomicBoolean as your "running" variable type instead.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that your `run` method does `while (running)`, but you set `running` to `true` *after* starting the thread.  I don't think the loop would ever run.  This may yield a race condition.

Comment: `Thread.join` means "block this thread until this other thread finishes executing".  Calling it against your *own* thread does not make sense.  I am not even sure what that would do.  Best case, it does nothing.  Worst case, it blocks forever.

Comment: @Brandon The `while(running)` runs fine.

Comment: Then it's luck.  That is the problem with race conditions is that you can test them and observe that it works, thus conclude that it *must* work.  Until such time that it doesn't and then you scratch your head for hours.  I suggest you fix it today.  It will save you headaches later.

Comment: @Brandon `Thread.currentThread().join()` is a sure deadlock.

Comment: @user1676075 `AtomicBoolean` brings nothing to the table over `volatile` if all you would call on it is `set` and `get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The thread blocks itself**
A thread ends, when the run method is finished, but you call the `join()` method inside the `run()` method and this method waits until the thread is finished. So the `run()` method never ends and the thread will never die.
 
You have done correct, to implement a while, which tests a boolean you can set in a method to end the thread.
To end the thread and waiting on its end, call the `join()` method after calling the `stop()`.
The `System.exit(0)` in the run method is not needed. If your thread ends and the join() method returns, the main method ends and so the program is finished.I know, your real program will be more complex, but you don't need `System.exit()`.

```
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        // Render, update etc...
    }
}

// The main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of Game and start it
    Game game = new Game().create();
    game.stop();
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
// Stop the game
public void stop() {
    // Set the program's running state to false
    running = false;
    game.interrupt();//Cause blocking methods like Thread.sleep() to end with an Interrupted exception
    game.join();//Wait until the thread is completed
}
```

Comment: So what I have done wrong is that I placed the call to `thread.join()` in the `run()` method?

Comment: Yes, that causes the thread to wait until its end but this will never happen. If you use the interrupt() method, the join() method would end and also the thread. But you must call interrupt from outside the run method. But there is no need to do anyhing after the wile.

Comment: So I should call the `thread.interrupt()` and then `thread.join()` in the `main` or `stop` method, and set `running` to false, to make the thread, and game stop?

Comment: Yes, look at EDIT1 and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should rewrite your run() method:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        // Render, update etc...

        // at the end, or after some steps, according to Java doc for Thread
        if (Thread.interrupted())  
           throw new InterruptedException();
    }
}
```

And your stop() method, simply interrupting the thread should do it:

```
public void stop() {
    thread.interrupt();  //use thread here, not game
}
```

Add a join() method:

```
public void join() throws InterruptedException {
    thread.join(); 
}
```

So in your main, you join your thread

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of Game and start it
    Game game = new Game();
    game.create();
    try {
        game.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //The interrupt should occur from another thread

        //Somebody called stop()
        //do your clean up
        System.exit(0);
    }           
}
```

This is the related [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()).

What is not clear to me yet, is how exactly you invoke stop().

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Stop is called when the `JFrame` is being closed.

Comment: I'll try it when on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to stop all your threads when your game exits from main.
You can setDaemon(true) to all your threads and they will be closed automatically.

Read about setDaemon in documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)

Comment: From documentation: The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads. 

So, it means if you have only daemon threads in you application, applications will be closed. And all threads will be closed too.